# New to Scrapy - How to scrape the entire website

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy. At the moment, I am trying to scrape the following website: https://blogabet.com/tipsters

You can find my current code bellow. However, as you can see from the website, it just loads the first 10 entries every time you visit it. I would like to scrape all the usernames and user-urls.

What I investigated so far is, that the page sends a new request to load the next 10 entries.

```
https://blogabet.com/tipsters/?f[language]=all&f[pickType]=all&f[sport]=all&f[sportPercent]=&f[leagues]=all&f[picksOver]=0&f[lastActive]=12&f[bookiesUsed]=null&f[bookiePercent]=&f[order]=followers&f[start]=10
```

My question is: How can I create a loop that scrapes all the usernames and websites?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.http import Request
from aufgehts.items import AufgehtsItem

class BlogmeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogme'


    def start_requests(self):

        url = "https://blogabet.com/tipsters/?f[language]=all&f[pickType]=all&f[sport]=all&f[sportPercent]=&f[leagues]=all&f[picksOver]=0&f[lastActive]=12&f[bookiesUsed]=null&f[bookiePercent]=&f[order]=followers&f[start]=0"

        headers={
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,pl;q=0.8,de;q=0.7',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Host': 'blogabet.com',
            'Referer': 'https://blogabet.com/tipsters',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }

        yield scrapy.http.Request(url, headers=headers)



    def parse(self, response):

        listenings = response.xpath('//*[@class="tipster-info col-lg-10 no-padding"]')

        for listening in listenings:
            username = listening.xpath('.//h3[@class="name-t u-db u-mb1"]/strong/text()').extract_first()
            link = listening.xpath('.//*[@class="e-mail u-db u-mb1 text-ellipsis"]/a/@href').extract_first()
            #registered = listening.xpath('.//[@class="col-sh-4 col-xs-2 col-lg-2 no-padding"]')

            yield {'Username': username,
                  'Link': link}

        next_page = response
            if next_page is not None:
                next_page = response.urljoin(
```

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inspected the website from where you are trying to implement pagination. There is an attribute of [start] in the URL. If you inspect multiple requests, you will notice that it gets incremented by 10 in every iteration. Here, you can create a loop where 10 is incremented to the existing number and then launch the request. You can use the library of `from w3lib.url import add_or_replace_parameters` and change the parameter by incrementing it by 10 in each iteration. You can change the existing `response.url` and create a Request through it using `from scrapy.spiders import Request`.

The question that remains is where should the loop end? I didn't tackle this question and left it for you. Best of Luck! [Check this image to understand the parameter that changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNuVs.png)